# Tricky proof problem based on definite integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $a+b=4$, where $a<2$ and let $g(x)$ be a differentiable function. If the derivative, $\dfrac{dg}{dx} > 0$ for all $x$, then prove that
$$\int_0^ag(x)\ dx + \int_0^bg(x)\ dx$$increases as
$(b-a)$ increases.

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated. This is the first time I have come across such a problem.

Comment: @mathmo123, thank you

Answer (score 9):

Put $t=b-a$, we find that $a=2-t/2$ and that $b=2+t/2$. Note that $t>0$ as $a<2$. Hence you want to show that the fonction
 $$F(t)=\int_0^{2-t/2}g(x)dx+\int_0^{2+t/2}g(x)dx$$ is increasing. But $\displaystyle G(y)=\int_0^y g(x)dx$ is differentiable, and $G^{\prime}(y)=g(y)$.

As $F(t)=G(2-t/2)+G(2+t/2)$, $F$ is differentiable and:

$$F^{\prime}(t)=-\frac{1}{2}g(2-t/2)+\frac{1}{2}g(2+t/2)$$

Now as $g$ is strictly increasing and $t>0$, we get $F^{\prime}(t)>0$ and we are done.